# Foolproof Debug Vs Release

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild, release

I am worried myself and the rest of my team will forget to switch the Solution Configuration drop down in VS from release to debug when debugging applications.

We have `#If DEBUG` checks littered through the code base to keep Emails, DB data changes, and File system changes from occurring (Slowly being refactored  using DI).

I've been contemplating using MSBuild or TFS to create a config file with some setting that indicates a release build.  This config file wouldn't be checked in.  The problem I see here is that if we deploy our apps and for whatever reason the config file is missing the apps will be silently writing to our dev dependencies.

We would also like to have the option to be able to run in a staging environment as well.

Is there a better way to handle this so that developers aren't an F5 away from writing to production or so that we don't deploy debug code to production?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to handle this so that developers aren't an F5 away from writing to production or so that we don't deploy debug code to production

- Never give developers physical access to production.  They should not have production credentials (connection string, etc) in their .config file, and they should not have physical access to production in any event.
- Use a build server to create builds for QA and for Production.  We use [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) but there are several good choices.

Comment: I definitely agree on the first part.  I'm new to the company and this is a small team.  I'm attempting to make this shift but it will be slow.

So the build server writes the configuration files for configuring all dependencies?

Comment: Yes.  We use SlowCheetah to transform the configuration depending on the build, and use TeamCity to create a build appropriate for QA or for Production.  We're also a small team, and find the investment in setting this up properly worthwhile.

Comment: Having one build per environment/configuration is wasteful and a bad practice. Good practice is one set of binaries, with configuration files being generated *at the time of release* from a template.

Answer (score 0):

I can say for sure that you need to get away from your approach which will be disastrous. Depending on developers to make that switch will never work out long term.

There are a many ways to handle this, the approach which we follow is:

- Created separate config files for each environment (DEV/IT/QA/PROD)
- On the servers, have a mechanism to mark the environment (registry
     or file or something)
- During deployment our scripts read the environment(from registry)
     and place the right config files. The advantage of this approach
     is that we dont need to have separate builds for DEV vs IT vs QA vs
     prod.

Comment: Hopefully you have a DEBUG build for DEV and a RELEASE build for other environments.  Deploying a non-optimized build to production is wasteful.

Comment: All builds till the branch is stable (first few days into ST) will be in DEBUG and rest everything will be in RELEASE.